# Flexbox layout, responsive image

Tags: flexbox

How can I 'flex' my images so they resize to the screen size? There is too much space around the images when viewed using my iPad. I'd like the images to resize proportionate to the screen size.

I've tried adding a 'flex' value to each image, but they don't resize.

I'm trying to use 'flex'. How can I size the images to about 1/5 of the screen width?

```
<View
    style={{
        height: "30%",
        flexDirection: "row",
        backgroundColor: "red",
        justifyContent: "space-between"
    }}
    >
    <Image
        source={require("../img/RGUC_Connect_logo.png")}
        resizeMode="contain"
        style={{
            flex: 5,
            height: undefined,
            width: undefined
        }}
    />
    <Image
        source={require("../img/logo.png")}
        resizeMode="contain"
        style={{
            flex: 5,
            height: undefined,
            width: undefined,
        }}
    />
</View>
```

Comment: I see that there are 2 different images, what is the expected resizing behavior ?

Comment: I need the image in the top left of page to resize to about 25% of the screen width, and the image in the middle to about 33% of the screen width

Comment: use `width: 25vw` property to adjust your div to 25% of the screen width